# javascript number of days calculation

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following code

```
// code set somewhere else on page
var ad = "2012-08-29";
var dd = "2012-09-03";

//my code
var a = new Date(ad+'T00:00:00');
var d = new Date(dd+'T00:00:00');
var nn = Math.ceil( parseInt(  ( d.getTime()-a.getTime() ) / (1000*60*60*24) ) );
```

`dd` should always be a date farther in the future than `ad`.

`nn` should be the number of *nights* between `ad` and `dd`, so in this example, I should have a value of 5 for `nn` (and it does, when i test it).

`nn` is being tracked (put into a GA variable, and also an Omniture variable) but about 50% of the time it is not getting a value.  We have triple checked and 100% ruled out that it is not a problem with the tracking itself (we have checked to make sure the tracking implementation is correct, and the (lack of) numbers are consistent between both GA and Omniture).

We are investigating to make sure `ad` and `dd` are always the expected yyyy-mm-dd format, and that `dd` is always a date farther in the future than `ad`, but assuming that that is shiny, **can anybody think of a reason why this calculation would fail?**

edit: to clarify, I don't think this calculation is failing, but I wanted a second (or 3rd!) opinion before ruling it out.

Comment: You should not use `parseInt` there - is has no effect.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "calculation fail"? There is no division through zero or such. Do you think it could throw an exception?

Comment: @Bergi: okay i can see how that might be superfluous but that wouldn't actually cause anything to fail would it?

Comment: A note: this kind of problem is a prime example of why it is important to use tools like http://jslint.com/ which validate your code. Had you run the code through jslint, you would have seen the error `Expected ')' to match '(' from line 8 and instead saw ';'` and thus noticed immediately the missing parens.

Comment: @Moses: actually that was a typo when posting the code here! sorry about that...(fixe)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parens in the final line of code. Including the final parens the code runs fine and `nn = 5` which I believe to be the desired result.

```
var nn = Math.ceil( parseInt(  ( d.getTime()-a.getTime() ) / (1000*60*60*24) ) );
```

Alternatively, you could remove the parseInt as Bergi suggested (it has no impact on the code). Just make sure that the parens match and you will be fine.

Comment: Hello Moses, thanks for looking at this! Unfortunately, that missing `)` was due to a typo while posting here, it is indeed in the code!

Comment: @mysql_noobie_xxxx this being the case, it is clear that we need to see a more complete picture of the code. As it is, this code compiles properly and returns the expected result, so without additional code all we can do is speculate.

Comment: yes, there are more moving parts to look at.  For example was the one I mentioned that we are investigating to make sure `ad` and `dd` have expected values.  My post here was to make sure I can rule *this* part out.  I didn't think *this* part is what is causing the issue, but I wanted to get a 2nd pair of eyes to confirm.  Thanks!